# Clipboard only holds data for as long as the source application is alive

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

I think there's been a change in how clipboard works in Windows 10 not so long ago. I was never noticing issues of this kind in prior versions of Windows, nor when Windows 10 came out. I'm only noticing it since maybe a year ago.

The change is that previously, you could copy a piece of text from no matter what application, close that application and paste it somewhere. But now you will find the clipboard empty. The text you copied only lives for as long as the application that provided it is alive. It's super annoying and makes trivial actions a pain. Is there a way to disable this new "feature" and make clipboard persistent?

I'm running Windows 1803 and 1809 on PCs where I notice this behavior.

Comment: Weird because I can't reproduce this behavior on the same version.

Comment: @CaldeiraG: I have noticed this multiple times on two different systems. Maybe it depends on which program you're copying from; I'll investigate and will update the question.

Comment: Raymond Chen had a post regarding this some time ago. Basically it went along the lines of "OS will tell the app that its data was requested to paste somewhere and then the app prepares it and sends to the paste location". iirc

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the names of some of the applications you've noticed this happening with.

Comment: Various programs exist that allow you to view and modify the Windows copy/paste buffer(s), as well as display them in different formats. Try using one of these to monitor what is happening.

Comment: @Kromster That's true. Some apps don't post the entire data to the clipboard. But rather handle the request to provide the data when Paste is invoke. The behaviour mostly depends on applications. I saw some apps asked whether I'd like to keep the clipboard data when I closed the app.